# How to get date and time from server in php

Tags: php, datetime

my problem is when the time and date stored in database the result in database is 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000. how do the results match with the current time and date???

for this i used following the code:

$dateandtime = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];

Comment: Use [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)?

Comment: Lots of options to get date from PHP; `date();`, `new DateTime();`, `Carbon\Carbon::now();`, etc. Take your pick.

Comment: It seems [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` is a unix timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#111471), so you might have to use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` when inserting into your database. If you show the code where you do the insertion, we might be able to help you better.

Comment: so you should use date('m/d/Y H:i:s ', time()); instead of $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];

Comment: What DB and column data type are you using? It looks like you're probably giving it a format it doesn't understand for that particular column so it's just defaulting to all zero's.

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa my DB data type is timestamp, i following this code:  $date = date('m/d/Y H:i:s ', time()); but nothing has changed

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Use `date()` as the function formats a local date and time, and returns the formatted date string. Example:-

```
  $date = date('m/d/Y H:i:s ', time());
```

This prints date and time in 24 hour format. For 12 hour with am/pm use:-

```
 $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s A', time());
```

I hope it help's you

Answer (score 0):

you try this code :

```
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
echo $now->format("m-d-Y H:i:s.u");
```

You can readily do this this with the input format U.u.

$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
echo $now->format("m-d-Y H:i:s.u");

> This produces the following output:
>
> 04-13-2015 05:56:22.082300 From the PHP manual page for date formats:
>
> U = Seconds since the Unix Epoch,
>   u = Microseconds
>
> Microseconds (added in PHP 5.2.2). Note that date() will always
>   generate 000000 since it takes an integer parameter, whereas
>   DateTime::format() does support microseconds if DateTime was created
>   with microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting the wrong format, it should be `Y-m-d H:i:s` don't be fooled by the fact that the name is similar as "timestamp" in PHP is different to "timestamp" in MySQL.